# How to avoid a separate log-in when adding WikiMedia references in a CakePHP framework?

Tags: cakephp, authentication, mediawiki

My team is trying to use Media Wiki to let users post deeper analysis of scientific research. However, MediaWiki requires a separate log-in, which is a real hassle.

Is there a way to bypass the need for a separate Media Wiki log-in so that the user who is already logged-in to our site can go straight to Wiki Media and post references without having to go through a separate log-in screen?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [add extensions to MediaWiki's authentication system](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:User_identity_extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your CakePHP auth works, though, the optimal solution would to be use an OpenID for both. You can install an extension to do this for MediaWiki.

See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OpenID

Another option would be to send a curl to log them into the wiki when the user successfully logs into your CakePHP application.